# Passing list of tuples to function arguments without modifying function definition

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

I want to call a function that accepts tuples as part of its arguments, i.e. the function is called as follows:

```
foo('Hello', (x1, x2), (y1, y2), (z1, z2))
```

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
arr = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Calling the function with `foo("Hello", *arr)` (as suggested by many answers online) doesn't work. It gives the error: `TypeError: foo() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'`

The function definition cannot be modified, i.e. I cannot change it to `foo("Hello", *arg)`.

---

**Edit:**  The specific function I'm using is cv2.rectangle, which draws a rectangle on an image. There are 3 tuples in the argument list: (x1, y1), (x2, y2) and a tuple of the RGB values e.g. (255, 0, 0). Because I need to call this cv2.rectangle function multiple times with different values, I store those values in a dictionary like this:

```
params = {
    key1: [(10, 10), (60, 30), (255, 0, 0)],
    key2: [(15, 15), (65, 35), (255, 100, 255)],
    key3: [(20, 20), (70, 40), (255, 0, 0)],
    key4: [(25, 25), (75, 45), (255, 100, 0)],
    key5: [(30, 30), (80, 50), (0, 100, 0)],
    key6: [(35, 35), (85, 55), (255, 0, 0)],
    key7: [(40, 40), (90, 60), (0, 100, 0)],
    key8: [(45, 45), (95, 65), (0, 100, 255)],
    key9: [(50, 50), (100, 70), (255, 0, 0)],
    key10: [(55, 55), (105, 75), (255, 100, 0)]
}
```

To call the cv2.rectangle function, of course I can just pass in params[key1][0], params[key1][1], params[key1][2], but I want to know if there is generally a more elegant solution for it, where I can do such thing as

```
cv2.rectangle(..., *params[key1], ...)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Hi, because the function is from a package.

Comment: If we saw the function signature, that might help. Is it always three tuples?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy the specific function I'm using is cv2.rectangle. Yes, there are 3 tuples in the argument list. Of course I can just pass in arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], but I want to know if there is a more elegant solution for functions with more tuples.

Comment: Your intention is unclear. Could you please edit your question to show the specific situation you care about?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I actually think it's a rather straightforward problem. But I edited it anyways to include my very specific use case. Is this more understandable to you now? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you need to call it multiple times with different values, the natural way to do this is looping over the sets of values you need to provide.

```
image = ...  # The first argument to cv2's `rectangle` function
for key, values in params.items():
    assert isinstance(values, list)  # Just checking!
    cv2.rectangle(image, *values)
```

---

Without access to your specific data (a minimal reproducible example), I created my own to show that this works.

```
In [1]: def foo(a, b, c, d, e=True, f="hi"): 
   ...:     print(a, b, c, d, e, f) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [2]: params = {"one": ['b', 'bee', 'beta'], "two": ['g', 'gee', 'gamma']}    

In [3]: for key, values in params.items(): 
   ...:     foo("hello!", *values, False) 
   ...:                                                                         
hello! b bee beta False hi
hello! g gee gamma False hi
```